# How to prevent high memory consumption caused by a aql-query returning a large result set?

Tags: artifactory

In our artifactory-pro 7.38 instance I discovered very high memory usage that I haven't seen before in artifactory 6. Now I have a memory dump showing me a stack trace that reveals the cause of the memory consume. When using a certain aql-query to filter all artifacts by a date, the jdbc-resultset seems to become very large (+20 mio items). While there a probably options to limit the result, I wonder how can I protect the instance against such situation. Is there a way it generally limit the size of the resultset in terms of number of results? I read that there is at least support to pass a limit along with the aql-query but is there something that can be done on the server side, such as enforcing pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Artifactory version **7.41.x** there has been an improvement to allow the system to kill long-running AQL queries exactly for this scenario, to avoid performance issues.

By default, the system will kill any queries that last more than 15 min. In case you want to change the default time for this you can add the following property to the `system.properties` file:

`artifactory.aql.query.timeout.seconds` - The query timeout for AQL, by default is 15mins (900 secs)

In addition, as you mentioned, it could be that the query can be improved. I recommend you to read [this wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-limitDisplayLimitsandPagination) regarding Limits and Pagination.

I hope this clarifies and helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Would be nice to have a server-side option to enforce pagination because a timeout will not prevent large queries to consume all heap-space. Another improvement I could see on artifactory side is generating the items iteratively while filling the send buffer with the response instead of producing the whole resultset but that is probably difficult to implement in a generic way for aql-query types.

Comment: Thank you for the additional input. It seems like valid points which can reduce the number of issues users encounter. 

You can submit feature requests in JFrog's JIRA -https://www.jfrog.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

If you don't have a user already, feel free to create one here - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/secure/Signup!default.jspa